# How to hide Plugins from wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na1I5.png)

I do not want to show these plugins to my user, please suggest to me if there are any ways to hide these plugins from the WordPress editor. I'm searching for a solution for a very long. I've got any solution to this yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can register new stylesheet for admin in theme `functions.php` file.

```php
function custom_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_styles' );
```

and hide the elements with the CSS. I think it should work but let me know if not working.

Answer (score 0):

@Sankalp Sounds like you are doing this for a client build. If that is the case one of the wordpress admin editor plugins would likely be your best bet. If you use Ultimate Dashboard plugin or Admin Menu Editor you can selectively hide elements of the wordpress admin side from users based on role or capability.